# Comparing columns of two Data Frames and returning the values of a different column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas. Given two data frames:

**df_1**

| product_id | product_price | invoice_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 100 | 200 |
| p2 | 200 | 300 |
| p3 | 300 | 600 |
| p4 | 400 | 700 |

**df_2**

| product_id | quantity | invoice_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 8 | 700 |
| p6 | 3 | 900 |
| p2 | 5 | 600 |

I want to check if the product id in df1 is similar to that of df2 and if so, pick the value of invoice total in df2.

I've tried the for loop:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df1.product_id:
   for j in df2.product_id:
      if i == j:
         # return the value of df2.invoice_total and append to the df_new.
```

But I believe there's a better way.

The result should be something like this:

| product_id | invoice_total |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | 700 |
| p2 | 600 |

Comment: What do you mean by similar? same product_id? if so, you can use merge

Comment: use pd.merge() to get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dataframe merge for this

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'product_id': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'],
    'product_price': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'invoice_total': [200, 300, 600, 700]
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'product_id': ['p1', 'p6', 'p2'],
    'quantity': [8, 3, 5],
    'invoice_total': [700, 900, 600]
})

df_merged = df_1.merge(
    df_2,
    on='product_id',
    suffixes=('_df1', '')
)
```

Contents of df_merged

```
  product_id  product_price  invoice_total_df1  quantity  invoice_total
0         p1            100                200         8            700
1         p2            200                300         5            600
```

Then filter to only the columns you need

```
df_merged = df_merged[['product_id', 'invoice_total']]
```

Final contents of df_merged

```
  product_id  invoice_total
0         p1            700
1         p2            600
```

Comment: I edited the question for further clarification. How do I get an output similar to the one above?

Comment: I have made edits to my answer based on your new requirements

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to do a "left join".

```
df_new = df1.join(df2, how = 'left')
```

then in df_new you can select the 'invoice_total' column and make a list of it by:

```
df_new['invoice_total'].values.tolist()
```

let me know if this is what you were looking for ;).